# How to Call Joomla Component into module?

Tags: php, module, joomla, components

I am using Joomla site, I want to call some controller+model+View of one component into module. How this possible.

I looking for code to using that we create object of Jcontroller and then get output of view into module, also View used some model for same component

Thanks
Manjeet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//set up any request variables that your component controller may need    
JRequest::setVar('var1','x');
JRequest::setVar('var2','y');

//include your controller and any other files
require_once(JPATH_BASE.'components'.DS.'your_component'.DS.'controllers'.DS.'yourcontroller.php');

//Do you need to tell your component you need module output?
$config = array();
$config['source'] = 'module';
$controller = new yourController($config);

$controller->execute('display');

//Reset any Request vars you have set
JRequest::setVar('var1','');
JRequest::setVar('var2','');
```